# Is there a way to tell what systems will scan your ship for contraband?

Tags: starfield

[Contraband](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/starfield-contraband) are illegal goods that sell for a high price to the Trade Authority.  However, when you enter some star systems, a scan can be performed on your ship by authorities and any contraband you have *may* be seized (pending the scan results).

**Is there an in game way to determine what systems will scan your ship** before you jump to them?  I want to be able to travel to systems with contraband without having it seized (I know there are ship upgrades and perks you can get to decrease the chance of scan detecting contraband, but I haven't modified my ship yet/obtained the perks).

Comment: I would certainly avoid any systems with major cities, except perhaps the Crimson Fleet homeworld, if you're on reasonable terms. The Den in the Wolf system seems to be the place to go.

Comment: @Neon1024 I know about The Den in the Wolf System (via the linked post), but I'm fairly early on in the game and its the only location I've reached so far that doesn't do a scan and has a trade authority.  The issue is, I have too much contraband and the Trade Authority's credits don't seem to replenish in a timely manner, forcing me to hold onto the contraband for a while.  So I'd like to know what systems I can travel to while holding contraband without losing it.

Comment: I guess it's the game mechanic to force you into finding a shielded cargo hold

Comment: Ancillary remark--this is a well-known problem with Bethesda games--you quickly reach a point where you are able to collect far more loot than the entire game economy can afford... including stolen goods that require fencing.

Comment: @TylerH I found that if you sit in a chair and wait 48 hours, the vendor credits seem to replenish.  So that is helpful for sure.

Comment: @TimmyJim Yep, also a Bethesda standard--wait a day (or two, since Skyrim) and vendor stocks (including money) always reset. A pain, to be sure, but at least it's manageable, until mods come along!

Comment: You can also avoid the scans if you fast travel directly to a planet -- as long as you aren't in the captain's seat, you'll jump straight to whatever location you're swapping to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only UC and Freestar Collective controlled systems that have a "faction town" in the system will scan you. You can tell if the system is controlled by either faction by the icon over the system, and a "faction town" with the icon over a planet/moon.

[image]

[image]

Systems like Wolf are UC controlled, but do not scan you for example. You can zoom into most systems so you can check to see if you see any of these planets.

[image]

[image]

If you have no shielded cargo and you're carrying contraband, you best avoid travelling to these systems lest they be confiscated.

Comment: Is that the symbol shown for both factions? I guess this  also has the caveat that you first need to visit the system to know if its controlled by them?

Comment: Yeah, the icon is shown for either faction. Though I believe you're right, you would have had to visit the system to get the icon. I think the icons would also have to be on one of the planets/moons for them to scan you.